# I need to color a particular link according to user operation

Tags: css

I need to color the link according to user's operation.
For example suppose I want set "unvisited color " to link:

```css
  a.newlink:link  {
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
<a href="/privacy" target="_blank" class="newlink">New link</a>
```

But it doesn't work. Anyone can help me?

Comment: @Mers my review was inapropriate, your suggestion must be rejected because it changes the code posted by OP. Even if you change the formatting you must preserve the original source code, no matter if it's wrong or right.

Comment: Thanks for the review, @Al.G. I'll keep that in mind for future edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since class name is applied to the same `a` tag, the rule should be `a.className`

```
  a.newlink:link  {
    color: red;
  }
```

**Example**

```css
a.newlink:link  {
    color: green;
  }
```

```html
<a href="/privacy" target="_blank" class="newlink">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.newlink:link  {
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
<a href="/privacy" target="_blank" class="newlink">new link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add a `class` or anything else!
You must want to use the `:not(:visited)` selector on your link:

```css
a:not(:visited) { 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="/privacy" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Hope it helps.